Indirect parametrization to multiple fixtures without increasing test scenarios
I have three fixtures
fixture_1, fixture_2, fixture_3. All three of these fixtures have dictionaries, and return a value based on the key provided.
I want to use indirect parametrization to output values based on each of my parameters.
For example, I have two test parameters: testp1 and testp2.
I need my tests to use each param as an input to all the fixtures, and then output the corresponding value and use them in the tests..
In summary, there will be only two scenarios ran (one for testp1 and one for testp2), but in each scenario the parameters are used as inputs to all three fixtures and get value from fixtures that correspond to them
Is this possible in pytest?
I was considering using:
@pytest.mark.parametrize('testp', ['testp1', 'testp2'], indirect=['fixture_1', 'fixture_2', 'fixture_3'])


I dont think there is a way to pass parameters to the subfxitures. Although you can use regular functions instead to implement such a logic, the following simplified code should work:
def fixture_1 (key):
    dict1 = {"testp1":0}
    return dict1 [key] if key in dict1 else None

def fixture_2 (key):
    dict2 = {"testp2":1}
    return dict2 [key] if key in dict2 else None

@pytest.fixture()
    def testp (request):
    res1 = fixture_1(request.param)
    res2 = fixture_2(request.param)
    if (res1):
        return res1
    if (res2):
        return res2

@pytest.mark.parametrize('testp', ['testp1', 'testp2'], indirect=True)    
def test (testp):
    print (testp)

    

The overall approach does not look readable so consider some refactoring to make parameter preparation more straightforward

Yes it can be done but the paramterisation should be written slightly different. You will need to provide param to the each indirect fixture independently.
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    ('fixture_1', 'fixture_2', 'fixture_3')
    [
        ('testp1', 'testp1', 'testp1'),
        ('testp2', 'testp2', 'testp2'),
    ],
    indirect=True
)

